# FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'test_text.txt'

Tags: python

The file "test_text.txt" is in the same folder as the program. it's a seperate folder from everything else that just has the text file and the program. unless I am misunderstanding what the error means, I just can't figure out what i'm missing or did wrong. i'm just reading a basics python book and this I pretty much copied it 1 for 1.

**CODE**

```
with open('test_text.txt') as test_text:
    reader = test_text.read()
    print (reader)
```

Comment: This only works if the "current directory" is set to that folder.  Are you running this from a command line, or from an IDE of some kind?

Comment: If the file is in the same folder the code should work like this. can you show your folder structure?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`FileNotFoundError` means you are trying to open a file that does not exist in the specified directory (in this case, whatever directory you are running your Python script from).

> the file "test_text.txt" is in the same folder as the program. it's a seperate folder from everything else that just has the text file and the program

In that case, you need to make sure that you're in the same directory as your file on your command-line, or specify the *full path* to `test_text.txt` (e.g. `/home/user/Desktop/test_text.txt`)

Comment: well stating the full path does work. a bit more work but a solution's a solution. thank you

Comment: If you don't put the full path, then Python looks in what it regards as the current working directory. That is often not what novices expect.

Answer (score 0):

`FileNotFoundError` occurs when you are trying to **access files** **outside the scope** of the application. In this case, the scope of your application is the folder in which you main python file resides.

There are **couple of ways** through which you can resolve this:

**1.** **Provide an absolute or full path to the file**: As mentioned by @pigeonburger in his answer, you can provide a **full path**. If you are using windows, then full path will be from `C:/Desktop/`

**2. Using a Relative Path**: Relative paths is the solution if both **the file you want to access and the python program are in the same folder**. Relative Paths start with **`./`** So, based on your file structure, the possible solution is this:

```
with open('./test_text.txt'):
  # your code
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Pointman for your answer. It did not work for me but it did lead me to what worked. I am using **Visual Studio Code** and I was having this issue with opening a text from a **Udemy course**.

```
jabber = open('Jabberwocky.txt', 'r')

for line in jabber:
    print(line)
    
jabber.close()
```

After running this code I would get the following error message

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: './Jabberwocky.txt'
```

I tried both the absolute path and the relative path option but they did not work for me. What I found that worked was once the terminal is open using Python you will have to traverse through your files until you get to the said folder or file. Once you do this then run the code and it will work.